# Add elements in python 2-D structure(like array, list or others) dynamically

Tags: python

I need to establish a 2-D structure to store elements in python but I can not figure out the number of columns and rows previously so I want to know how to build a structure in python in which I can add elements in row and columns freely and dynamically.
What I want to do is like something in Matlab:
A(i,j)=k;
where A is a data structure such as matrix in Matlab

Comment: Do you need specific columns and rows, or just pushing them onto the structure? If its the latter, simply use append(). Also, I'd suggest giving it an honest shot and coming back with any errors you encounter. It helps us help you when you give a starting point.

Comment: GIve me code GIve me code Give me code

Answer (score 2):

```
a = []
a.append([])
a[0].append('a')
print(a[0][0])
```

It is similar to 'array-of-arrays' in other languages. And it has not to be rectangular - you can have first 'row' 10 elements long and second one only 3 elements long.

Read more about 2D lists in Python [here](https://www.dotnetperls.com/2d-python).

Answer (score 1):

You can do two-dimensional arrays using dicts, and you can do sparse arrays that way, but it's not very speed-optimized:

```
>>> a = {1: {2: 2, 3: 4}, 2: {4: 5, 6: 7}}
>>> a[1]
{2: 2, 3: 4}
>>> a[1][3]
4
>>> a[1][3] = 10
>>> a
{1: {2: 2, 3: 10}, 3: {4: 5, 6: 7}}
```